# How could the director know that Alexander has changed?

Tags: travelers

Light subplot spoilers ahead. It's about the fate of a boy named Alexander.

In one episode the main characters save the live of a boy named Alexander, who would have died otherwise.

Later they are ordered to kill the boy, because he will become a mass murderer or something like that.
McLaren takes care of the boy and has a few hours of talk with him. In the moment when he takes his gun to shot the boy from behind he is ordered to cancel the mission, because his talking has influenced the boy in a way that he now will not become a mass murderer any more.

My Question is : How could the director know this?

Explanation:

Saving the boy, they changed the timeline. The director saw from historical records that the boy became a mass murderer and ordered the team to kill him in the past.
McLaren talks to the boy and then intended to shoot him.

If he shot him, the director could not learn from historical records that the boy was changed by the talk and didn't became a mass murderer any more, because the boy died (and has no chance to show and prove that the talk changed him).

If he didn't shoot him, the boy would have developed into a normal man, and the director could see by the historical records, that the talk with McLaren completely changed the boys fate. But in this case there is no need for him to tell McLaren not to shot the boy - because he didn't.

So how did the director know, that the talk would change the boys fate if he would not be shot?

Comment: Inherent in many time travel stories is the implicit idea that just as the present is moving forward, so is the future. The story logic implies that as our viewpoint in the present moves forward by one hour, so does the relevant point in the future from which any interaction with the present will take place. Some time travel stories make this explicit in their lore (can't cross the time streams, or whatever), but I don't recall if Travelers did that.

Comment: @Harabeck : I know that concept and it is a very useful and interesting one. But I don't think, it would help here. How should the director be able to see the consequences of the talk, without the consequences of the shooting shortly after? That would mean that from his point of view there is a timeline in which McLaren talks to the boy but didn't shoot him. I don't see how that should work out.

Comment: Well, to use another common assumption in these stories, the future isn't set until a critical point is passed in the present. The talk is done, so its consequences are set in stone in the future. The shooting hasn't happened yet in the present, so it is "softer" and can be interfered with from the future. No, that doesn't actually make sense. Time travel doesn't make sense in the first place. The interesting part of time travel stories is how they try to reconcile the paradoxes. Again, I wish I could remember all of the rules set up in Travelers and formulate a proper answer.

Comment: Yeah. Exactly my point. My main interest in time travel stories is how they "bend the rules" to prevent or deal with paradoxes and how far they succeed in making it hard to find logical errors. :-) On the first glance travelers seems to avoid many problems, by it's unique setup. But unfortunately only a few rules are established explicitly. How changes in timeline (and perception of it by the director) work and which rules and restrictions there are is completely left in the dark, at least on screen. I hopes for interviews and words of god I didn't found yet.